# Other keys not working when using keydown event for arrow keys in KnockoutJs

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have the following binding on a div:

```
<div class="my-class" tabindex="0" data-bind="event:{keydown:function(data, event){onKeyDown(event)}}">
</div>
```

On document load, I bring focus to the div using:

```
$('.my-class').focus();
```

I do the following inside script to handle up and down arrow keys whenever the div is in focus:

```
onKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 40 || event.keyCode == 38) {
        // My logic
    }

    return true;
}
```

The up and down arrow keys work fine on the div. The problem now is that whenever the div is in focus, the keys other than up and down arrows does not work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value `true` returned from `onKeyDown` is not received by Knockout since there's no return statement in the keydown binding inside HTML.

Change the HTML to the following and it should work:

```
<div class="my-class" tabindex="0" data-bind="event:{keydown:function(data, event){return onKeyDown(event)}}">
</div>
```